# Flutter: how to get currency symbol from currency code

Tags: flutter, dart

From language code it's easy:

```
var format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: "es");
print(format.currencySymbol);
```

But the only thing I have is `EUR` for euro, so the currency code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: _language); // doesn't really matter what language you pass
print(format.simpleCurrencySymbol("EUR"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NumberFormat().simpleCurrencySymbol('USF') // $
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/simpleCurrencySymbol.html